# Trying to get grunt to copy directory to destination directory

Tags: gruntjs

I've been working a lot with grunt lately and trying to get up to speed on all the awesome things I can do with it. What I am attempting to do is set a variable for a src, and one for a destination directory and run a copy task to move my initial build files (updated from another source) to production destination directory. I can get the copy to work with this simple example but it brings over the src directory /build/ to assets

```
assets/js/build/vendor-library
```

I'm trying to not copy over the directory name build. so the copy just has the following /assets/js/vendor-library/*

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    copy:
      main:
        expand: "true"
        src: "build/vendor-library/*"
        dest: "assets/js/"


  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-copy"

  grunt.registerTask "default", "copy"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `flatten` option.

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    copy:
      main:
        expand: "true"
        flatten: "true"
        src: "build/vendor-library/*"
        dest: "assets/js/"


  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-copy"

  grunt.registerTask "default", "copy"
```